Using nginx to reach vuejs/vite app on a different container
I have two repositories, one in PHP and another with Vue.js/Vite. Both repos are for the same app. I have one container for the Vue.js repo and another for the PHP repo. Both are working fine independently.
I want to connect them as follows:

If my request uses a specific path, it should use the Vue.js app.
Otherwise, it should use the PHP app.

I added another container with Nginx to handle this redirection. Here is the configuration:
  location /vuejs/ {
        log_not_found on;
        log_subrequest on;
        add_header X-Nginx-Matched "Location for /vuejs/ matched";
        proxy_pass http://vuejs:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    

In a way, it's working fine. If I try myapp/test, the PHP app is used. If I try myapp/vuejs, it makes a request to my Vue.js container, but it only retrieves the index.html file. All assets are requested from the Nginx container and result in 404 responses.
I'm looking for a solution to get the entire page, including all assets, as a response.
